# Hints to improve performance in nested for loop?

Tags: r

In a 100x100 matrix populated only with integers, I am performing pairwise comparisons WITHIN each row beginning with (and including) element 1,1. For any comparison that is TRUE, I tally a +1 at the corresponding element in another preallocated matrix [x] (this is just a similarity matrix).

Using nested for loops, this operation requires N*(N-1)/2 + N comparisons for each row. On my machine, the code below doesn't take too long but is there a better (ok, faster and more elegant) way to this? I have considered a vectorized calculation using "apply" but as of yet, with no joy.

```
result <- matrix( round(rnorm(10000,sample(5))), ncol=100)
x <-matrix(data=0, nrow=100,ncol=100)

system.time(
for (i in 1:100) {
  for (j in 1:100) {
    for (k in j:100) {
        if (result[i,][j] == result[i,][k]) {
        x[j,][k] = x[j,][k] + 1
        }
    }
  }
}
)
user  system elapsed
6.586   0.599   7.192
```

Here's a small example:

"result" matrix

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    6    1    1
[2,]    6    1    5    3
[3,]    1    5    4    4
[4,]    2    3    4    2

structure(c(1, 6, 1, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3, 1, 5, 4, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2), .Dim = c(4L,4L))
```

After the code application, I expect in the x matrix:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    4    0    1    2
[2,]    0    4    0    0
[3,]    0    0    4    2
[4,]    0    0    0    4
```

Comment: Please include machine-readable code for the small `result` example.  `dput` does this nicely.

Comment: OK, no I get, the entries in x are j,k entries, not i,j entries.  I'm not getting why you did this but it's clearly not the prior answer I wrote.

Answer (score 5):

This is about 100 times faster (50ms) on my machine using your 100-by-100 `result` matrix:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(result))
   for (j in i:ncol(result))
      x[i, j] <- sum(result[, i] == result[, j])
```

And this is about 200 times faster, but maybe a bit harder to understand:

```
x <- apply(result, 2, function(y)colSums(result == y))
x[lower.tri(x)] <- 0
```

If it is still not fast enough for your taste, I would look if this exact function is not already implemented in one of the many distance packages, or try a `Rcpp` implementation. Although I'm not sure you'll get a lot more out, as my suggestions already use a fair amount of vectorization.

Comment: Excellent work. I get the first solution vectorizing the 3rd for loop; the 2nd one using apply is what I was trying to achieve, without success. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Good job, I realized my error answering before going to sleep last night and woke up and the answer was already up.  :)